# Get some data from Telegram by ThingsBoard rule-engine

Tags: telegram-bot, thingsboard

For demo purpose i need to get data from telegram bot to be analyzed in rule-engine of ThingsBoard...  is it possible to do it directly(not using database for that or kind of that), like send message to bot then get & parse response? What should i use for that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

> send message to bot then get & parse response

You can implement that using RPC call and response, one way to do it is to define a device (representing your bot) and have your bot connect through mqtt and subscribe for RPC calls

.